# R JSON to tibble

Tags: r, json, tibble

I have the following data passed back from an API and I cannot change it's structure.  I would like to convert the following JSON into a tibble.

```
data <- '{    "ids":{
      "00000012664":{
         "state":"Indiana",
         "version":"10",
         "external_ids":[
            {
               "db":"POL",
               "db_id":"18935"
            },
            {
               "db":"CIT",
               "db_id":"1100882"
            }
         ],
         "id":"00000012520",
         "name":"Joe Smith",
         "aliases":[
            "John Smith",
            "Bill Smith"
         ]
      },
      "00000103162":{
         "state":"Kentucky",
         "external_ids":[
            {
               "db":"POL",
               "db_id":"69131"
            },
            {
               "db":"CIT",
               "db_id":"1098802"
            }
         ],
         "id":"00000003119",
         "name":"Sue Smith",
         "WIP":98203059
      } ,
     "0000019223":{
        "state":"Ohio",
        "external_ids":[
           {
              "db":"POL",
              "db_id":"69134"
           },
           {
              "db":"JT",
              "db_id":"615234"
           }
        ],
        "id":"0000019223",
        "name":"Larry Smith",
        "WIP":76532172,
        "aliases":[
           "Test 1",
           "Test 2",
           "Test 3",
           "Test 4"
        ],
        "insured":1
  }   } }'
```

**Please Note: This is a small subset of the data and could have thousands of "ids".**

I've tried `jsonlite` and `tidyjson` with a combination of `purrr`.

The following gives me a tibble, but I cannot figure out how to get aliases back.

```
obj <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data, simplifyDataFrame = T, flatten = F)
obj$ids %>% { 
    data_frame(id=purrr::map_chr(., 'id'), 
           state=purrr::map_chr(., 'state', ''), 
           WIP=purrr::map_chr(., 'WIP', .default=''), 
           #aliases=purrr::map(purrr::map_chr(., 'aliases', .default=''), my_fun)
           ) 
}
```

I cannot figure out with `tidyjson` either:

```
data %>% enter_object(ids) %>% gather_object %>% spread_all
```

What I would like back is a tibble with the following fields (regardless if they are in the JSON or not.

```
id
name
state
version
aliases -> as a string comma separated
WIP
```

BONUS: ;-)

Can I get external_ids as a string as well?

Comment: Also, it is not clear about the format you need `external_ids`.  It is a `data.frame` with 2 column

Comment: any type of comma seperated string

Comment: I updated the answer with `external_ids'

Comment: Please see the latest example.  This is a small set of data, but it could have thousands of entries.  I should have made that clear.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of extracting each element with multiple calls with `map`, an option is to convert to `tibble` with (`as_tibble`) and `select` the columns of interest, grouped by 'id' collapse the 'aliases' into a single string and get the `distinct` rows by 'id'

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfr(obj$ids,  ~ as_tibble(.x) %>% 
             select(id, one_of("name", "state", "version", "aliases", "WIP")))  %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(aliases = toString(unique(aliases))) %>% 
    distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   id [2]
#  id          name      state    version aliases                     WIP
#  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                     <int>
#1 00000012520 Joe Smith Indiana  10      John Smith, Bill Smith       NA
#2 00000003119 Sue Smith Kentucky <NA>    NA                     98203059
```

---

If we also need the 'external_ids' (which is a `data.frame`)

```
map_dfr(obj$ids,  ~ as_tibble(.x) %>%
         mutate(external_ids = reduce(external_ids, str_c, sep = " "))) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(aliases, external_ids), ~ toString(unique(.))) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   distinct(id, .keep_all= TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  state    version external_ids           id          name      aliases                     WIP
#  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                  <chr>       <chr>     <chr>                     <int>
#1 Indiana  10      POL 18935, CIT 1100882 00000012520 Joe Smith John Smith, Bill Smith       NA
#2 Kentucky <NA>    POL 69131, CIT 1098802 00000003119 Sue Smith NA                     98203059
```

#### Update

For the new data, we can use

```
obj$ids %>%
    map_dfr(~ map_df(.x, reduce, str_c, collapse = ", ", sep= " ") )
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  state    version external_ids           id          name        aliases                          WIP insured
#  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>                          <int>   <int>
#1 Indiana  10      POL 18935, CIT 1100882 00000012520 Joe Smith   John Smith Bill Smith             NA      NA
#2 Kentucky <NA>    POL 69131, CIT 1098802 00000003119 Sue Smith   <NA>                        98203059      NA
#3 Ohio     <NA>    POL 69134, JT 615234   0000019223  Larry Smith Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Test 4 76532172       1
```

Comment: This gives me 4 rows and I need 2 for this example.

Comment: @mattjvincent. The `aliases` seems to be different if you check the 1st and 2nd row.  Not clear what to do with multiple names for `aliases`.  Do you want only the first/

Comment: Yes, but I need rows 1 and 2 combined. And rows 3 and 4.

Comment: @mattjvincent. WIll you be okay with `do.call(paste, c(obj$ids[[1]]$external_ids, list(collapse=",")))#
[1] "POL 18935,CIT 1100882"`

Comment: Actually this solution will not work with the elements listed above.  I added a 3rd id and it now fails with: ``Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 2: Column `external_ids`
* Length 4: Column `aliases```

Comment: @mattjvincent. Thanks, I updated the solution using your new dataset

Comment: Thanks for the solution!